# Is there any problem in my code ? I need to pass the 'string' selected in Header component to app component by services methods used in Angular

Tags: angular

I am creating a Shopping list project and I tried to pass a selected data from my header.component.html to app.component.ts via services and then tried to just console.log in app.component.ts .
But i see that nothing is being printed in the console.log statement of app.component.ts and neither i am receiving any error .

Here is the also the gist link to it and code is below too.Any help will be highly appreciated.

https://gist.github.com/ratnabh/87847c8396a32436b8a751eb5bb08ae8

I have used the services here.

Header.component.html

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="navbar-header">
  <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Recipe Book</a>
</div>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a href="#" (click)="clicked('recipe')">Recipes</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" (click)="clicked('shoping')">Shopping list</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" role="button">Manage<span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Save Data</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Fetch Data</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Header.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Headerrecipe } from './header.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.css'],
  providers:[Headerrecipe]
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private heservice:Headerrecipe) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  clicked(e:string){

  this.heservice.stringselected.emit(e)
  }

}
```

Header.service.ts

```
import { EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

export class Headerrecipe{

  stringselected=new EventEmitter<string>()
}
```

App.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Headerrecipe } from './header/header.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  providers:[Headerrecipe]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
  selected='recipe'
  ngOnInit(){
   this.heservice.stringselected.subscribe((item)=>{
   this.selected=item
   console.log(this.selected)
   })
  }
  constructor(private heservice:Headerrecipe){}
}
```

Comment: You should read this: https://angular.io/guide/architecture-services#providing-services. Providing services in the component (which is what you are doing), rather than in a root module, means the component get its own copy of the service. Communication like what you want can't work that way.

Comment: service should be "@Injectable()". Just add @Injectable() above export syntax.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Angular v6 or higher, you can register the service with the root Angular injector using this syntax:

```
import { EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class Headerrecipe{

  stringselected = new EventEmitter<string>()
}
```

Then the service does *not* need to be included in the `providers` array of any module or component.

Registering a service in this way registers it with the root Angular injector, which provides a shared instance. So you can use this technique to share data between any of the components of the application.

Answer (score 0):

In your header service maybe consider using a `Subject` from rxjs
then create a method that updates the value of that Subject in the service ex

```
// header.service.ts
selectedRecipe: Subject<any> = new Subject();


chooseRecipe(recipe: string) {
    this.selectedRecipe.next(recipe);
}
```

```
// header.component.ts

yourClickMethod(recipe: string) {
   this.heservice.chooseRecipe(recipe);
}

your app component logic would stay the same, the subscribe will work the same way.
```